# Перетаскивание кнопки в Delphi

Tags: delphi

Суть вот в чем: Допустим, у нас есть форма с кнопкой на ней. Координата кнопки 33:33. Как сделать так, чтобы кнопку можно было перетаскивать по форме (естественно в запущенной программе)? При этом по достижению определенной координаты совершалось действие нажатия на кнопку.

Answer (score 3):

Есть два варианта. Либо вручную делать с помощью события движения мыши, чтобы при зажатой левой кнопке мыши кнопка на форме следовала за курсором, либо использовать стандартные функции.
**Простой способ** - с помощью события движения мыши. Описываем булеву переменную drag. При событии OnMouseDown присваиваем drag:=true, т.е. разрешаем перемещение. В обработчике события OnMouseMove присваиваем координатам кнопки координаты мыши, так же, как было сделано в таймере, но с условием if drag then [наши действия]. И, наконец, при событии OnMouseUp сбрасываем переменную - drag:=false.
Пример кода:

```
{...код...}
var drag:boolean=false;
{...код...}
procedure TForm1.Button1MouseDown; {кнопка нажата и удерживается}
begin
  drag:=true; {можно двигать}
end;
procedure TForm1.Button1MouseUp; {кнопка отпущена}
begin
  drag:=false; {нельзя двигать}
end;
procedure TForm1.Button1MouseMove;
begin
if drag then {если можно двигать, то двигаем}
begin {добавляем -5 и -30, чтобы учитывалась рамка формы}
  button1.left:=mouse.CursorPos.X-form1.Left-5;
  button1.top:=mouse.CursorPos.y-form1.top-30;
end;
end;
```

**Другой способ такой:** свойству DragMode кнопки присвоить dmAutomatic (кнопка перемещается автоматически), ну и свойству DragKind - dkDock (кнопка будет стыковаться с другими объектами, как я понял). Далее. У некоторых компонентов, особенно с большим и пустым рабочим пространством (форма, панель, всякие бары), есть свойство DockSite - чтобы кнопка садилась на этот компонент, это свойство должно иметь значение true. Правда, кнопка может случайно оказаться сама по себе, не пристыкованной, поэтому нужно быть аккуратней (у неё появится заголовок и кнопка закрытия, т.е. пользователь может её случайно уничтожить). Зато это удобно. Кстати, тут есть дополнительные события: OnDragDrop, OnDragOver, OnStartDock, OnStartDrag, OnEndDock, OnEndDrag. Надеюсь, разберёшься с ними сам, если понадобится.

Comment: Блин чуток опоздал, пока набирал) Но ваш ответ подробнее, так что +1 вам)

Answer (score 0):

А в чем проблема?)

Обрабатываем событие, когда мы мышкой зажали кнопку, MouseDown вроде) Ну, к примеру есть переменная типа boolean Down, присваиваем ей true. Далее обрабатываем событие на форме, когда мы передвигаем курсор мыши, MouseMove. Здесь пишем что то вроде этого:

```
if( Down = true)
begin
 button1.Left = X-10;
 button1.Top = Y -10;
end;
```

где X, Y - текущие координаты мыши;

Если у кнопки положение задается через Location типа TPoint, то соответственно меняем их.

Далее, к примеру если мы достигли некоторой позиции по X и Y, то вызываем button1.Click();

Ну я думаю логика ясна, у меня Delphi щас не стоит, так что полного кода привести не могу.

Творите!

Answer (score 0):

Если помогло нажми +

свойство Drug and Drop не пробывал использовать? не лучший вариант но самый легкий
в свойствах кнопки измени

```
DragKind - dkDock
DragMode - dmAutomatic
```

или вот показан подход к этому вопросу( на англ, но все понятно)
[link text](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nebIdYOk-XE)